# Refreshing a Pivot Table connected to SSAS in Excel refreshes the whole workbook

Tags: excel, ssas

We have a user with an Excel workbook with multiple pivot tables connected to SSAS.
We've found that when we do a `Refresh` on a pivot table (not `Refresh All`), it updates all pivot tables in the workbook.

This is causing issues as it takes too long to refresh the whole workbook.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Refresh on a pivot table will refresh all data dependent on that SSAS connection. So one solution for you would be to make multiple connections to the same SSAS source rather than building all the pivot tables off the one connection.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I had a feeling it was something like this. When you say "connection".. what exactly are we talking about? A connection file? Some of our users use a connection file and others always create a new connection by typing in the server name.

Comment: Either way has the same effect. If you create a new connection then the properties are saved into a new file anyway.

Comment: OK so what is the purpose of `Refresh All` then? The thing is, we have 2 workbooks, one connected to our legacy data warehouse and one connected to the new one. The legacy pivot updates in a few seconds (and the profiler shows it only updating that pivot), however the new workbook updates all the pivots. The new pivot refreshes fine when I move that tab to its own workbook.

Comment: If Refresh refreshes all data dependent on one connection, then the point of Refresh All would be to refresh all data dependent on all connections.

Comment: Got ya. I have a feeling this might have something to do with Links in the workbook. Going to see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains it nicely:

https://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/08/pivot-refresh-vs-update-is-there-a-real-difference/

Basically, as MattClarke mentioned, refreshing in Excel refreshes all pivot tables connected to that connection, whereas Refresh All will refresh all connections (you might have a connection to 2 cubes for example).